# how can i animate fbx model by changing frames in xna

Tags: xna, 3d-modelling, fbx

i am simulating a tennis game and i have a tennis player which i made with 3d max and it has
frames for each movement and exported it as fbx model but i don't know how to use this frames to animate the player inside the xna code .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the [Skinned Model Sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model) and related educational material you will find how to do character animation using XNA.

The main trick is "rigging" the model for animation using a set of bones and then specifying animations in terms of those bones. This way the animations can be bound to any other model that has the same bone structure, and animations can be blended (say, swing the racket and run at the same time).

Be warned, this is a fairly advanced technique, as it requires quite a lot of work from the programmer and the artist to get right.